# If I want to do something when some state is changed, I can't find a graceful way to do this

Tags: reactjs, redux

I encapsulated a component base on select, it's like search select, a key feature is linkage.

For example, a province select and a city select, when I change the province select, the city select will update its options to corresponding cities. I want to encapsulate this linkage feature to component.

The process is like this:

Users change the province

=> Component dispatches an action to change the province state

=> The city select found that the state of the province select has been changed

=> The city select dispatch an action to change its own state

I can't find a way to implement this feature gracefully with Redux

Comment: why not list out your cities by province and then when you change the province you dynamically change the city list by name?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a textbook example of how to use Redux; I couldn't imagine what could be the problem. Anyway; this is how I would do it.

One dumb component: `Select`

Two smart components: `ProvinceSelect`, `CitySelect`

Two reducers: `provinces: { all, selected }`, `cities: { all, selected }`

One action: `SELECT_PROVINCE`

Both the provinces AND the cities reducer should change their states on the `SELECT_PROVINCE` action. `provinces` should update its `selected` property and `cities` should update its `all` property.

Comment: Yes, this solution works but it's not a graceful solution. The CitySelect could be a public component in npm, it could only provide an action to users to change its type. So my question is : Can I dispatch an action when some state is changed, so that change another state?

Comment: I might be horribly misunderstanding this. Please let me know if what I'll write is totally out of scope:

CitySelect is a **domain component**; smart component in redux terminology. It is only valid in your application (domain) just like any other smart component so you shouldn't be considering publishing it to NPM.

Only publish your generic / dumb components into NPM, providing as many props / hooks with sensible defaults so that I can use them in my Mobx app and you can in your Redux app for example. From other programmers persp: I don't want your application internals, I have my own.

Comment: That being said, if you still want to publish a Redux behaviour, you might checkout some examples like: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form
Currently you can extend Redux by store enhancers, middleware and higher order components. Google each and try to see if you can get a generic enough implementation that still works and useful for others to publish to NPM. I believe you can try both the store enhancer and the middleware depending on how you approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in React-Redux, component get all the state  inside mapToState call, now its upto you to decide, which state changes you wanted  to listen in your component.

I will approach like this

=> Users change the province

=> Component dispatches an action to change the province state

=> The city select  listen to province state and update the city  inside mapToStore

=>  and city will call the render to update the component.